# PresentView and UIAnimation view conflicts?

Tags: ios, uiview, uianimation

It looks like i am having some interesting conflicts between PresentView transition and the UIAnimations. In short, the user should be able to tap on a button graphic in a view, View A. This button should pulse on tap; and then go to the next view, View B by a dissolving transition. When arriving on ViewB; there should be an animation played by UIAnimation.

The code below shows the calling code from ViewA to View B:

```
    [WizzAnimationManager pulseOnce:buttonToPulse toSize:0.9 withDuration:0.15];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2];

    UIStoryboard* mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    WizzPlayViewController* vc = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WizzPlayView"];

    vc.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES         completion:Nil];
```

The problem is that the UIAnimation from ViewB is supposed to translate from one side of the screen to the other. With the code above, the "end" animation is only shown but no translation. In other words, it is like the UIAnimation is not executed.

Now, when i set the PresentViewController flag "Animated" to NO; the translation of the View B UIAnimation works fine; however the pulse animation from ViewA  no longer work (as long as the crossDissolve transition of course).

I cannot quite figure out the relation between both the transition between one view to another, and the animation of ViewB; but i can sense there is a conflict of priority between both

Has anyone met a similar issue?  Thanks in advance for any tips you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On AnotherView You have to execute animation code after delay then it will appear to that it's working.

[self performSelector:@selector(animationCode:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];